# SDTT says @type is unspecified when using JSON-LD relational context

Tags: json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to create a relational context in JSON-LD. My objective is to specify the type of data of a schema type.

Example: All Actors are Person, all Directors are Person and all Person have only one property Name.

```json
{
    "@context" : {
        "actor" : {
            "@type" : "http://schema.org/Person",
            "@id" : "http://schema.org/actor"
        },
        "director" : {
            "@type" : "http://schema.org/Person",
            "@id" : "http://schema.org/director"
        },
        "Person" : {
            "@type" : "http://schema.org/name",
            "@id" : "http://schema.org/Person"
        }
    }
}
```

But Google's SDTT doesn't recognize the `@type` and says it's unspecified. How do I give the context here? I want the SDTT to recognize the Actors and Directors by name.

```json
{
    "actor" : ["Johnny Depp", "Christina Ricci"],
    "director" : "Tim Burton"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [`@type` in the context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#typed-values), you are providing a **value type**, not a **node type**:

> A ***node type*** specifies the type of thing that is being described, like a person, place, event, or web page. A ***value type*** specifies the data type of a particular value, such as an integer, a floating point number, or a date.

I don’t think JSON-LD 1.0 offers a way to set the node type in the context.